# ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

I installed tensorflow-gpu. I am using the virtualenv installation for Tensorflow.

```
Ubuntu version 16.04
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
Nvidia Driver:390 (latest)
```

I have already linked cuda to my .bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/extras/CUPTI/lib64
```

When I try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I receive the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/rosi/udacity/TensorFlow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Your tensorflow version requires CUDA 8 -- this is cearly spelled out in the installation instructions, if you care to read them

Comment: I did uninstall 9 and installed 8 and now I am receiving: ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok I have fixed all the errors, thanks @talonmies

Answer (score 1):

After last apt upgrade, I faced same issue with nvidia-390.30 and CUDA 9.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with deb (network).
nvidia-smi command was missing.
/usr/local/cuda/extras/demo_suite/deviceQuery returned error 35.

The issue surfaced because when i ran the following command:

```
# prime-select query
```

it was returning undefined

Since I do not have an intel GPU onboard, I ran the following command as root

```
# prime-select nvidia
```

and then relogged in as it adjusted user profile, and other links.
Now CUDA 9.1 works just fine with Nvidia driver 390.30 :), also nvidia-smi command also started working.

Note: Users with Optimus setups (Intel GPUs) may want to try this instead:

```
# prime-select intel
```

I ran

```
/usr/local/cuda/extras/demo_suite/deviceQuery
```

and it detected device perfectly.